# Use url parameter in class based view Django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a view (CreateWorkRelationView) that makes use of the CreateView CBV. In the URL, a parameter is passed (user) that I need to refer to a lot. Is it possible to set the object user **outside** the functions in my class? So are you able to access kwargs from outside a function?

So I basically just want to add the following line to my class

```
user = get_object_or_404(Contact.pk=kwargs['user'])
```

At the moment however, that returns

> NameError: name 'kwargs' is not defined

This is my class

```
class CreateWorkRelationView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'groups/group_form.html'
    form_class = WorkRelationForm
    model = WorkRelation
    title = "Add a work relation"
    success_message = "Workrelation was successfully created."


    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = get_object_or_404(Contact, pk=self.kwargs['user'])
        form.instance.contact = user
        return super(CreateWorkRelationView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('contacts:contact_detail', self.kwargs['user'])
```

The reason why I would like to do this, is:

1. I want to use this object in my title string.
2. I am going to add a couple of more functions, and they all need this object.

Comment: If you're looking for the logged in user you can use self.request.user but I may be missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that can't possibly work; you don't have a user, or kwargs, or even a request at the time the class is defined. You need to do this inside one of the methods called at request time; probably `get_context_data` or `get_object`.

Comment: But am I able to reference tot this context_data in other functions?

Comment: If you assign it to an instance attribute, yes.

Answer (score 3):

The way I managed to do this is to use a FormView.

In my urls.py i have

```
regex=r'^my/path/(?P<pk>\d+)$',
```

In my views

```
class MyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = self.kwargs['pk']
```

It works well.

Comment: Why so long for this answer to get a +1? Thanks, wasted hours until I stumbled on this answer.